# Xamarin ListView not binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just start learning xamarin and I know I should go to MVVM approach but before that I want to try the code behind binding but it is not working.
I can see there's 2 lines in mobile but I can't see the binding value. Why?

**TestListView.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinTabbed.Views.TestListView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="MyLV">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black"  />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Status}" TextColor="AliceBlue"  />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**TestListView.xaml.cs**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class TestListView : ContentPage
{
    public TestListView ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        MyLV.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Employee> {
            new Employee { Name = "t1", Status = "tt" },
            new Employee { Name = "t2", Status = "t2" }
        };
    }

    public class Employee {
        public string Name;
        public string Status;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Name` and `Status` in your `Employee` class must be **properties**, not fields for binding to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class should look like this. As **@jsanalytics** mentioned in the comment. **Name** and **Status** should be properties, not fields.

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```